# How do you set the order that parameters are processed in SQLAlchemy's custom SQL constructs?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In SQLAlchemy I'm trying to nest a built-in 'concat' call inside of a custom built group_concat call. Both are being passed strings as parameters, but the strings are being reversed when the query is rendered/executed.

Example:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.sql import expression
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.sql import select
from sqlalchemy.sql.functions import concat


class group_concat(expression.FunctionElement):
    name = "group_concat"


@compiles(group_concat, 'mysql')
def _group_concat_mysql(element, compiler, **kw):
    separator = compiler.process(element.clauses.clauses[1]) \
                    if len(element.clauses) == 2 else "','"
    return "GROUP_CONCAT(%s SEPARATOR %s)" % (
                compiler.process(element.clauses.clauses[0]),
                separator,
            )

table = Table(
    'test_constructs', MetaData(),
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('column1', String(255)),
    Column('column2', String(255)),
    Column('foreign_id', Integer(11)),
)


def select_records():
    column1 = table.c.column1
    column2 = table.c.column2
    test_query = select([
        table.c.foreign_id,
        expression.label('clean_test_column',
                         group_concat(concat(column1,
                                             ',',
                                             column2),
                                      '|')),
    ]).group_by(table.c.foreign_id)
    res = engine.execute(test_query)
```

The logging output from this is:

```
2012-06-01 09:48:29,552 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT test_constructs.foreign_id, GROUP_CONCAT(concat(test_constructs.column1, %s, test_constructs.column2) SEPARATOR %s) AS clean_test_column FROM test_constructs GROUP BY test_constructs.foreign_id
2012-06-01 09:48:29,552 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('|', ',')
```

...notice that the order of the parameters that is being substituted into the query is reversed. '|' is being substituted into CONCAT and ',' is being used by GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: Are you sure the log output is for the code you are showing? The variable `separator` is being directly interpolated into your `GROUP_CONCAT(...)` string by your group_concat compiler, yet your log output shows it as a bind parameter.

Comment: I am sure. The only thing that I removed from this code was the engine creation step and the `if __name__ == "__main__": select_records()` Otherwise it is exactly as I executed it from the command line.

Comment: I'd put in a `pdb` breakpoint in `_group_concat_mysql` to verify this; your log statement seems to indicate that your code isn't being executed; unless sqlalchemy parses out string literals again after the fact.

Comment: It looks like it is. If you replace `"GROUP_CONCAT(%s SEPARATOR %s)" % (` with `"GROUP_CONCAT({0} SEPARATOR {1})".format(` you end up with the same thing. I'll try the pdb route...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is because the separator was being "compiled" first, but added to the string second. Thus it was ending up in the correct order in the statement, but reverse order in the params.

Instead I'm doing:

```
@compiles(group_concat, 'mysql')
def _group_concat_mysql(element, compiler, **kw):
    return "GROUP_CONCAT({0} SEPARATOR {1})".format(
                compiler.process(element.clauses.clauses[0]),
                compiler.process(element.clauses.clauses[1]) \
                    if len(element.clauses) == 2 else ",",
            )
```

...which seems to work properly.